# Radiobuttonfor default all unchecked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model as below

`public class TestModel
    {
        public string SE { get; set; }
    }`

Then i have an interface and implementing class, Businesslogic class as below.

`public interface ITest
    {
        List<TestModel> SE();
     }`

```
 public class Test : ITest
{
  public List<TestModel> SE()
    {
        SEBLL B=new SEBLL();
        List<TestModel> lstSeries = new List<TestModel>();
        lstSeries = B.SE();
        return lstSeries;
    }
}
```

my Business logic class where i bind data from database or sometimes manually

```
public class SEBLL
{
    public List<TestModel> SE()
    {
        List<TestModel> e = new List<TestModel>();
        e.Add(new TestModel{ SE = "A" });
        e.Add(new TestModel{ SE = "B" });
        return e;
    }
 }
```

my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ITest s = new Test();
        List<TestModel> lstSeries = s.SE();
        return View(lstSeries);

    }
```

Finally here is the stronly typed view.

```
@model IEnumerable<TestModel>    
 foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => item.SE, item.SE, new { @id = "SE", @class = "radio" })
                SE @item.series
            </label>
        </div>
    }
```

I need both of the Radiobuttons to be unchecked intially.

I am bit new to MVC, radiobutton list is populated with 2 values, but always anyone value is being selected when view initially loads. i tried setting checked html property but that did not help.

please let me know where am i going wrong in the whole process.
Correct me with the process too if i am following wrong flow.

Comment: Could you please correct the code, because I am not able to see class TestBModel model.

Comment: Corrected it is just TestModel, please correct me whether the procedure i am following is correct.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You cannot use the same property for the options. You need a model with a (say) `string SelectedOption` and `List<TestModel>` Options` and then its `foreach (var item in Model.Options) { @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedOption, item.SE, new { id = "", @class = "radio" })`